# Get only the PK value, and return in from django table

Tags: django, data-extraction

I want to search against the `Tld` table, only get the primary key value of the `Tld` object.

I have the code to perform a query to extract the whole row, but i only want the PK value matching the query:

```
Model.objects.filter(d=bu)
```

In plain sql what I'm trying to:

```
SELECT id from Model where d=<buv>
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question but why you didn't use a query like `my_query = Tld.objects.get(pk=1)`

Comment: Because the `d` field is searching based on a `base_url`  see updated plain sql of what im trying to do

Comment: You can use `only` method to get specific column from your table.

    `Tld.objects.filter(d=base_url).only('id')`

Same way you can use `defer` method when you don't want some specific column.

    `Tld.objects.filter(d=base_url).defer('name')`
See their documentation for more details.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#only

Comment: Thanks @SK.FazleeRabby !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're perhaps looking for this:

```
Tld.objects.filter(d=base_url).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does in plain sql terms

Comment: It does `SELECT TLD.id from TLD where TLD.d = <base_url>` which you can see by printing the value of the `.query` attribute of the `QuerySet`.

Comment: How's this compare in terms of performance to `.only('id') ` ? Do you know

Comment: The underlying SQL looks to be exactly the same, but `.values_list` returns a list whereas `.only` returns a `QuerySet` which would get evaluated when you did something with it. I guess you'd need to measure to determine any performance difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks @Will - just wondering if possible to override whatever method I choose to a string? Is `values_list()` valid in Django 2. ? Last questions. Thanks

Comment: You mean convert the id value you get back from the query into a string?

Comment: Yeah you mention `only` provides a queryset, is it possible to convert this directly to a str or int ?

Comment: You'd can iterate the queryset and extract the id `[t.id for t in Tld.objects.filter(d=base_url).only('id')]`